# Pyglet move sprite position from a for loop instead of using pyglet clock

Tags: python, for-loop, pyglet

I writing my first pyglet app to visualize some calculation another script makes.
Unfortunately I'm stuck and can't figure out where to go next.

I'm trying to move a sprite from its position to another position using a for loop,
so at the end of the each loop it changes the sprite position relative to the old position a specific distance calculated by the loop.

This is a simplified version of the code I'm writing (I hope this will help others with a similar problem, then copy my own specific project).

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

def update(yd):
    Ball.y += yd

distance = [2,1,3,-2,-3,2,4,-5,1,2,3,-4,3,5,2,-2,3,2,3,-2,]

### test update in loop ###

for i in distance:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    update(i)


### Run app ##

pyglet.app.run()
```

I don't want to use the `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update())` because the loop can take longer to calculate then the `clock.schudule`, the movement will not be smooth but that's fine.

The problem I have is nothing happens until the loop is finished, only after python runs through the loop it calls `pyglet.app.run()`, but if I call `pyglet.app.run()` before the loop, it will only run the loop after I close the pyglet windows.

Comment: shouldnt you run on_draw() in the loop or in the update?

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN no, pyglet is an event driven framework, and `on_draw` is repeatly called by pyglet itself when the main loop was startet with `app.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

When using `pyglet`, you're not in control of the main loop of the program.

The main loop is started by `pyglet.app.run()`, and you can hook into events with the `window.event` decorator.

You run your loop before the main loop is started. That's why it seems that nothing happens.

If you want to call `update` every 0.1 seconds, you should use `clock.schedule_interval`, which takes a function to call and an interval parameter. If you want to move your sprite once for each value in `distance`, you can make use of an iterator and a nested function, like:

```
def update():
   g = iter(distance)
   def inner(): 
       try:
           update(next(g))    
       except StopIteration:
           pass
   return inner

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update(), .1)
```

---

Edit in response to your comment:

Given your loop:

```
for i in distance:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    update(i)
```

you can turn it into an iterator:

```
def calculate():
    for i in distance:
        time.sleep(0.1) # just some expensive calculation
        yield i
```

and use it inside `on_draw()`:

```
calc = calculate()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
    try: update(next(calc)) 
    except StopIteration: pass
```

Comment: so I call pyglet.clock.schedule_interval() inside my loop? my problem is I don't know how long the loop will take to calculate, at the end of the loop I have a variable with the time it took to calculate and the calculated distance. that is the reason I'm trying to call the update() as the last line of the loop

Comment: on the loop in the question I put that time.sleep(0.1) to simulate the time the loop takes to calculate, the loop has a lot more code inside which is not relevant for the piglet question

Comment: @user2879397 Maybe I misunderstood your problem. So you basically have a loop, and in this loop you want to do *expensive calculation, then update sprite position* multiple times? If so, you can use the same technique (using an iterator) and simple use it in `on_draw()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I got it I think, call the update() I made in the question in the event on_draw(), it works. Something super strange is happening thought, the loop stops and some random place and only continuous when I move the mouse inside the pyglet window. maybe this should be another questions?